# What is the next closest divisor in an array?

Tags: algorithm

Example
input = [10,4,5,2,1,8,4]
output = [5,2,1,1,__X,4,__X]

I am not sure how to achieve to solution with less than o(n^2) time complexity.
Any help ??_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/232130)

Comment: Shouldn't it be [5,2,1,1,X,4,2] ?